# How to pass one component reference to the other in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have main page with two components -- States and Commands. The issue is States component should get a reference to the Components one. From I've read I could use cascading parameters to achieve my goal.

Main page:

```html
<CascadingValue Value="commands">
    <States @ref="states"></States>
</CascadingValue>

<Commands @ref="commands"></Commands>

@code
{
    private Commands commands;
    private States states;
    ...
```

States components:

```html
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public Commands Commands { get; set; }
}
```

In theory it should work, visually they are rendered correctly, but under the hood it does not work -- States component receives "null" for Commands so basically it does not "see" the other component.

And here is "funny" part -- as I wrote States component receives null, but if I refer in main page to Commands component it is like Blazor realizes it is set already and it is time to pass the new value to States and indeed States receives not-null value. Some lag effect or something?

Of course I would like to make it happen automatically. How to do it?

*Visual order does not make any difference, when I put on main page Commands first, and then States I get exactly the same result.*

**Workaround**:

The simplest workaround I know is (I use the names from my example) adding backing field to "commands" and changing "commands" to a property. Whenever setter is called simply call `StateHasChanged` at the end and that's it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You'd like to access `Commands` data in `States`?

Comment: @AndrasCsanyi, yes, exactly. For various operations States need to notify Commands about it, so basically Commands does not know anything about States, but States does and needs access to Commands.

Comment: I would take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#pass-data-across-a-component-hierarchy) and the event handler solution too.

Comment: @AndrasCsanyi I am confused -- I showed cascading parameters have lag effect and you post a link to cascading parameters. How does this help solving the problem?

Comment: If that doesn't help, then the second part of my answer which is about events might help.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you probably don't yet have a good grasp of the component rendering process and what's going on.  `States` may well get rendered before `Commands` - the order is dictated by what they do and when they stack their first render event onto the Renderer queue.

If `States` renders first the Cascading Parameter that is passed to it is null.  `commands` isn't set until `Commands` is first rendered.  Any rendering cycle after that happens passes a valid value for the Cascading Parameter to `States`.

This is not a good design. You should only cascade a component like this:

```
<Commands @ref="commands">
  <CascadingValue Value="commands">
    <States @ref="states"></States>
  </CascadingValue>
</Commands>
```

`Commands` definitely exists before `States` gets rendered.  `States` will always get a valid object.

Comment: CascadingParameter is not just a parameter, it should be refreshed automatically. Secondly in your code the layout dictates the logic (data flow). So of course such tying components as you presented is a good approach when it is the case, but the question is how to tackle this in general case.

Comment: if you must do what you have shown above, i.e. two unconnected components with one/two way communications, you need to implement a state service.   One component raises and event in the service and the other gets the notification via an event.  Search for Blazor Notification Service.

Comment: Got a link?  Unfortunately when I search for "Blazor Notification Service" all I get are a bunch of results about Toast components.

Comment: Use Bing and you get better results.  Here's a few SO answers - ~ https://stackoverflow.com/a/76258228/13065781 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69562295/13065781 - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76447173/can-a-blazor-element-access-data-in-a-peer-element