# Blazor Server Notify UI outside of component

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

My application upload a list of components into our ERP.
The upload process can take 1 or 2 minutes. I would like to notify in real time the user what is going on.

I created a blazor server app. I have the razor page with some UI logics but I didn't want to put all the processing logic inside the razor page. So I put it into a worker.

How the worker can push notification to the blazor component ?

I red about SignalR, but they are mostly about blazor webassembly or too basic for me to see how I can apply it to my situation.

I was wondering what is the good approach ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the Notification pattern.  The service - what you call a worker - raises an event whenever a change happens.  Any UI components that need to know about the change register an event handler on the service event.  Normally the event handler just calls `StateHasChanged`.

Here's a Stackflow answer that demonstrates the Notification pattern using the WeatherForecast list. [How can I trigger/refresh my main .RAZOR page from all of its sub-components within that main .RAZOR page when an API call is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69558006/how-can-i-trigger-refresh-my-main-razor-page-from-all-of-its-sub-components-wit/69562295#69562295)