# Blazor server side pass an object instance as parameter to nested component

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

Here a page, `myPage.razor`

```
@page "/myPage"
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <ComponentA />
    </div>
</div>
```

In the `ComponentA` I use a `ComponentB`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <ComponentB />
    </div>
</div>
```

In the `myPage.razor.cs` there is an instance of a class `Person`. I'd like pass this instance to `ComponentA` and to `ComponentB`.

I tried with `[Parameter]` and `[CascadingParameter]` without any success.

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks,

Update 1:
The Microsoft sample below works but that's not do what I want (below the child code). Microsoft

```
@page "/parameter-parent"
<h1>Child component (without attribute values)</h1>
<ParameterChild />
<h1>Child component (with attribute values)</h1>
<ParameterChild Title="Set by Parent"  Body="@(panelBody)" />
@code {
    PanelBody panelBody = new PanelBody() { Text = "Set by parent.", Style = "italic" };
}

//Child
@using Testing.Pages
<div class="card w-25" style="margin-bottom:15px">
    <div class="card-header font-weight-bold">@Title</div>
    <div class="card-body" style="font-style:@Body.Style">
        @Body.Text
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; } = "Set By Child";

    [Parameter]
    public PanelBody Body { get; set; } =
        new()
        {
            Text = "Set by child.",
            Style = "normal"
        };
}
```

But I have to receive the object (not create a new one), display in an `<input type="text"/>` be able to change the text. The new value is update in the object in the `ParameterParent`. I tried the code below but Body is null all the time (the parent is the same then code above), I tried `CascadingParameter` too

```
@using Testing.Pages
<div class="card w-25" style="margin-bottom:15px">
    <div class="card-header font-weight-bold">@Title</div>
    <div class="card-body" >
        @Body.Text
    </div>
</div>

<InputText id="name" @bind-Value="Body.Text" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; } = "Set By Child";

    [Parameter]
    public PanelBody Body { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Parameter` works. Post what you actually tried. The code you posted has no parameters

Comment: I know, it's the code I would like to add parameter.

Comment: You wrote `without success`. What *did* you try and what didn't work? Have you checked the [docs on component parameters?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#component-parameters) - add `[Parameter]` to the property you want to expose in `ComponentB` and use that as an attribute, eg `<ComponentB MyProperty=@_whatever />`

Comment: I tried the same solution than Henk below, I got the same error described in the comments (compilation ok) but error at runtime

Comment: @Kris-I have you tried the *documentation* examples? Parameters work. All components, even the built-in ones, use `[Parameter]`, not some internal black-box mechanism. I've been using component parameters for two years. People can't guess what's wrong with code you didn't post. I'd bet you didn't add the parameter in `ComponentB`. Or you tried to use a string literal instead of `@(_someField)` to pass the value

Comment: The code from Microsoft work. But not what I want to do. See the Update 1 in the initial post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do multi-component two way communications.

You can create a notification service and subscribe components to notifications - here's a question and answer that shows you how to do that [How can I trigger/refresh my main .RAZOR page from all of its sub-components within that main .RAZOR page when an API call is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69558006/how-can-i-trigger-refresh-my-main-razor-page-from-all-of-its-sub-components-wit/69562295#69562295).

Here is how to do it with a cascaded context object with notifications - similar in many ways to `EditContext`.

First the context object.  We don't mix delegates and events with our data objects, so we create a specific object for the purpose that contains our edit model and it's associated events.

Here's `PersonEditContext`:

```cs
public class PersonEditContext
{
    public Person Person { get; set; } = new();
    public Action? Updated { get; set; }

    public void NotifyUpdated()
        => this.Updated?.Invoke();
}
```

Next `ComponentA`.

It:

1. Picks up the cascaded context and create an `EditContext` from the `Person` instance.
2. Wires up a handler to the edit context's `OnFieldChanged` event which raises the Action in the `PersonEditContext` cascaded instance.
3. Wires up a handler to the `PersonEditContext` cascaded instance `Updated` Action to trigger a render event on the component.
4. Implements `IDisposable` to tear down the handler wiring.
5. `itsMe` prevents a render event if the component itself raises the event.

```cs
@implements IDisposable

<h3>ComponentA</h3>
<div>@personContext.Person.FirstName</div>
<div>@personContext.Person.LastName</div>
<p></p>
<hr />

<EditForm EditContext=this.editContext OnValidSubmit=HandleValidSubmit>
    <!-- Input2 -->
    <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="personContext.Person.FirstName" />
</EditForm>

@code {
    private EditContext? editContext;
    private bool itsMe;
    private Person person => personContext.Person;
    [CascadingParameter] private PersonEditContext personContext { get; set; } = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        editContext = new EditContext(person);
        editContext.OnFieldChanged += OnFieldChanged;
        personContext.Updated += Updated;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
    }

    private void OnFieldChanged(object? sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        itsMe = true;
        personContext.NotifyUpdated();
    }

    private void Updated()
    {
        if (!itsMe)
            StateHasChanged();

        itsMe = false;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (editContext is not null)
            editContext.OnFieldChanged -= OnFieldChanged;

        if (personContext is not null)
            personContext.Updated -= Updated;
    }
}
```

And `MyPage` which is very similar:

```cs
@page "/"
@implements IDisposable

<EditForm EditContext=this.editContext OnValidSubmit=HandleValidSubmit>
    <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="person.FirstName" />
</EditForm>

<CascadingValue Value="personContext" IsFixed="true">
    <ComponentA />
    <ComponentB />
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    private EditContext? editContext;
    private PersonEditContext? personContext;
    private Person person => personContext?.Person ?? new();
    private bool itsMe;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        personContext = new PersonEditContext { Person = new Person { FirstName = "Nancy", LastName = "Dvolio" } };
        editContext = new EditContext(person);
        editContext.OnFieldChanged += OnFieldChanged;
        personContext.Updated += Updated;
    }

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        // Whatever
    }

    private void OnFieldChanged(object? sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        itsMe = true;
        personContext?.NotifyUpdated();
    }

    private void Updated()
    {
        if (!itsMe)
            StateHasChanged();

        itsMe = false;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (editContext is not null)
            editContext.OnFieldChanged -= OnFieldChanged;

        if (personContext is not null)
            personContext.Updated -= Updated;
    }
}
```

Here's `ComponentB` to demonstrate the multi-component behaviour:

```cs
@implements IDisposable
<div class="bg-primary text-white p-2 m-2" >
    <h3>ComponentB</h3>
    <div>@person.FirstName</div>
    <div>@person.LastName</div>
</div>

@code {
    private Person person => personContext.Person;
    [CascadingParameter] private PersonEditContext personContext { get; set; } = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        personContext.Updated += Updated;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private void Updated()
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (personContext is not null)
            personContext.Updated -= Updated;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I copy the @code {} section to MyPage.razor.cs, I get plenty of error 'editContext' does not exists, personContext does not exist, StateHasChanged does not exists. Any idea why ? The files are named ComponantA.razor and ComponantA.razor.cs with a partial class in named with the same name than the component

Comment: Can you show your MyPage.razor and MyPage.razor.cs.  Your errors suggest you probably have a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather straightforward:

```
@page "/myPage"
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <ComponentA Item="myItem" />
    </div>
</div>

@code { ItemType myItem = new(); }
```

and

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <ComponentB Item="Item" />
    </div>
</div>

@code
{
  [Parameter] public ItemType Item { get; set; }
}
```

Component B should have exactly the same Parameter as Component A.

Comment: Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'ComponentA' does not have a property matching the name 'Item'. By the way the intelliSense does not set Item property

Comment: @Kris-I `[Parameter]` works. I've been using components with parameters for the last 2 years. Post the *actual* code you tried. Something others can copy and try to compile

Comment: The compilation is ok it's when I load the page the problem. Is it normal than 'Item" property does not appear in the  intellisense ? I tried with a simple string and not an object I get the same error 'MyPage' does not have a property matching the name 'Item'.