# How to use service to share data between components?

Tags: c#, blazor

How to use ChildContent to set service property and share between component that have same inject? i got empty collection. the first step, if Header component have property to set. It add item to collection. Inside Table component i check if service have items or not. I have problem to control flow which to render first.

**Lifecycle Service**

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<TableService>();
```

**Header.cs**

```
public class Header 
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

**TableService.cs**

```
public class TableService
{
    public List<Header> Headers { get; set;} = new();
}
```

**Header.razor**

```
@inject TableService TableService

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Name { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        TableService.Headers.Add(new Header { Name = this.Name });
    }
}
```

**Table.razor**

```
@inject TableService TableService

@foreach (var header in TableService.Headers)
{
   <span>@header.Name</span>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; } 
}
```

**Index.razor**

```
<Table>
  <Header Name="Id"/>
  <Header Name="Email/>
</Table>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76258228/13065781  and https://stackoverflow.com/a/75944088/13065781

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis i update my TableService to use ObservableCollection that have CollectionChanged event. Table component listen to that event on Table first Initialized if CRUD operation do StateHasChanged(). Still empty.  [Check this](https://pastebin.com/NVWYVxZB)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like code from a dynamic table.

First, do you really want the scope of your `TableService` to be for the lifetime of the SPA and shared by multiple instances of your table?

My guess is no, so you need to scope the your `TableState` object to the page holding the table.  You can use a cascade to make it available to all the page components.

Here's my `TableState`.  It controls access to the list to trigger `HeadersHaveChanged` events when things change.  I've changed the `Header` object to a simple readonly struct to make it and the `Headers` property immutable.

```cs
public readonly record struct Header(string Name);

public class TableState
{
    private readonly List<Header> _headers = new();

    public IEnumerable<Header> Headers => _headers.AsEnumerable(); 
    public event EventHandler? HeadersHaveChanged;

    public void AddHeader(Header header)
    {
        _headers.Add(header);
        this.HeadersHaveChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

My `Index` now looks like this:

```cs
<CascadingValue Value="_tableState" IsFixed>
    <Table>
        <Header Name="Id" />
        <Header Name="Email" />
    </Table>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    private TableState _tableState = new();
}
```

`Table` looks like this.  It renders the child content on the first render [which registers the columns] and renders the column code on subsequent renders.

```cs
@implements IDisposable

@if (_firstRender)
{
    @ChildContent
    _firstRender = false;
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            @foreach (var header in _tableState.Headers)
            {
                <th>@header.Name</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </table>
}

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private TableState _tableState { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    private bool _firstRender;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(_tableState);
        _firstRender = true;
        _tableState.HeadersHaveChanged += this.OnHeadersChanged;
    }

    // Do a yield to get the first render
    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
        => await Task.Yield();

    private void OnHeadersChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        => this.StateHasChanged();

    // Isn't absolutely necessary in this casde as the _tableState object is of the same scope
    public void Dispose()
        => _tableState.HeadersHaveChanged -= this.OnHeadersChanged;
}
```

And `Header`

```cs
@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string Name { get; set; } = "Not Set";
    [CascadingParameter] private TableState _tableState { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(_tableState);
        _tableState.AddHeader(new(Name));
    }
}
```