# How to send data back from MudDialog

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, mudblazor

How can I send data from `MudDialog` (child) back to the component that instantiates the dialog (parent).

Sample class:

```
class Data
{
    string Name;
    int age;
}
```

Comment: Which DialogService ?

Comment: blazor has [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0#eventcallback) here to show how we pass data from child to parent. We might define `EventCallback` parameter in child component, and when we use child componenet in the parent component, we set the event handler method as the value of the `EventCallback` parameter. And ms doesn't have a document to use "DialogService"

Comment: OP has been using MudBlazor before, so I presume MudDialog.

Comment: You need to implement a version of the Notification Pattern.  Whether it's a cascade or 
 service depends on the required scope.  See these questions and answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/75944088/13065781 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76170542/web-event-handling-in-multiple-windows-blazor and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76447173/can-a-blazor-element-access-data-in-a-peer-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you close the Dialog component using `MudDialog.Close<T>()` You can return a `T` object from the dialog.

*CustomDialog.razor*

```cs
<MudDialog>
    <DialogContent>
        <MudForm Model="PassedData">
            <MudTextField @bind-Value="PassedData.Name"></MudTextField>
            <MudNumericField @bind-Value="PassedData.Age" Variant="Variant.Text" Min="0" Max="500" />
        </MudForm>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MudButton OnClick="Cancel">Cancel</MudButton>
        <MudButton Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="Submit">Submit</MudButton>
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>


@code {
    [CascadingParameter] MudDialogInstance MudDialog { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public Data PassedData {get;set;}

    void Submit() 
    {
        MudDialog.Close<Data>(PassedData);  
    } 
    void Cancel() => MudDialog.Cancel();
}
```

Then in the page/component you show the dialog you can use the `DialogService.GetReturnValueAsync<T>()` method to  get the returned object.

*Page.razor*

```cs
@code {
    Data _returnedData = null;
    private async Task OpenDialog()
    {    
        DialogOptions dialogOptions = new DialogOptions() { CloseOnEscapeKey = true };
        Data dataToPass = new(){Name="John", Age= 40};
        DialogParameters dialogParamters = new ()
        {
            ["PassedData"] = dataToPass
        };
        var dialog = await DialogService.ShowAsync<CustomDialog>("Custom Dialog", dialogParamters , dialogOptions);
        var result = await dialog.Result;
        if (!result.Canceled)
        {
            var returnedData = await dialog.GetReturnValueAsync<Data>();
            _returnedData = returnedData;
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look at this
[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QkQnFOQrUqRBBxbr)