# Problem in render data after fetch the data from Api controller in Blazor

Tags: async-await, blazor, rendering

I have a Blazor solution that contains 3 projects:
client
server
shared
After I send a request from client to the server (web api controller in server project)
I can get the data, but I have to get the data asynchrony:

```
    @page "/News"
    @using BlazorAuthorize.Models;   
    @inject HttpClient Http;
    @code {
    private NewsList _news {get;set;}
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                _news = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<NewsList>>("News/GetNews");          
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { throw ex; }
        } 
}
```

but Blazor doesn't render the data in the page.
if I add a record to the "_news" like this:

```
     var newsitem = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<NewsList>("News/GetNews/{id}"); 
_news.Add(newsitem);
```

the items on the page don't change and I can't see the added item until I click on a button or set new value for a parameter or property.

Comment: If "Blazor doesn't render the data in the page" then it can't show changes either. The description is unclear, the code is missing at least the Controller .

Comment: The data from the controller is fetched correctly, but not rendered on the page.

Comment: You need use something like the Notification pattern - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76256650/i-need-to-update-state-of-blazor-component-when-other-component-changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because OnInitializedAsync() call asynchrony function will cause thread to render UI,It will cause the UI to be rendered before the data is obtained,you need to use StateHasChanged() when after obtaining data

Comment: Could you give me a sample code? 
I can't find StateHasChanged() in blazor.

Comment: ```protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    persion.Add(await NewPersion());
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#state-changes-statehaschanged
You can consult the microsoft documentation